# DIY Slider simple pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, slider

I've been searching, but I cannot find anything about this in the documentation, unless I'm missing something. I'm using this simple DIY Slider http://jsfiddle.net/kGRRK/ and I want it to display the current slide.

Like this:
**3 of 5**
Or this:
**- - X - -**

Is there a simple line of code to place here to achieve this?

```
$(".slider").diyslider({
   width: "400px",
   height: "200px",
   display: 1,
   loop: false,
});

$(".current-slide")

// use buttons to change slide
$("#go-left").bind("click", function(){
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "back");
});
$("#go-right").bind("click", function(){
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/ba5jh/? First link from Other live examples http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider?

Comment: Is this what you wanted ?http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/493/

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys! @dreamweiver your version seems to work, but it adds one more slide to the counter than there actually is. I ended up with a code much simpler than I thought: http://jsfiddle.net/CGBVF/

So that's what I needed. Just out of curiosity is there any way to get the slides to display as "- - X - -" with the X marking the current slide?

Comment: @Pascal: i hope this is what you were expecting,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/CGBVF/3/

Comment: @dreamweiver Oh haha I might have explained myself wrongly, sorry for that! I meant like the first slide "X - - - -", second "- X - - -", third "- - X - -", etc. Each - represents a slide, then placing the X at the current slide.

Comment: I thought so, what would that serve :). anyway here you go ,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/CGBVF/18/

Comment: @dreamweiver you are my hero! Exactly how I meant, I was able to change the number to an X easily. My questions have been answered! Thanks very much.

Comment: @Pascal: Your welcome, lets do one more final thing, close this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

**HTML CODE:**

```
<button id="go-left">&laquo;</button>
<button id="go-right">&raquo;</button>
<div class="slider">
<!-- The slider -->
  <div>
    <!-- A mandatory div used by the slider -->
    <!-- Each div below is considered a slide -->
    <div class="a">Div #1</div>
    <div class="b">Div #2</div>
    <div class="c">Div #3</div>
    <div class="d">Div #4</div>
    <div class="e">Div #5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="counter">
  <!-- counter --> <span class="current-slide"></span> of <span class="total-slides"></span>
</div>
<div class="currentSlide"><span class="cur-slide"></span>
</div>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
// hide the message when the slider ends moving, and update the counter

$(".slider").bind("moved.diyslider", function (event, slide, slideNumber) {
  slideNo = "";
  $("#counter .current-slide").text(slideNumber);
  curSlide = $("#counter .total-slides").text();
  index = 1;
  while (index <= curSlide) {
      if (index == slideNumber) slideNo += " " + slideNumber + " ";
      else slideNo += " - ";
      index++;
  }
  $(".cur-slide").text(slideNo);
});

// initialize the slider
$(".slider").diyslider({
   width: "400px",
   height: "200px",
   display: 1,
   loop: false,
   start: 1
});

//set the slider index initially to first slide
$(".cur-slide").text("1 - - - -");

// set the counter's slides count once the slider has been initialized
$("#counter .total-slides").text($(".slider").diyslider("getSlidesCount"));

// use buttons to change slide
$("#go-left").bind("click", function () {
  $(".slider").diyslider("move", "back");
});
$("#go-right").bind("click", function () {
  $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
div.a {
   background: red;
}
div.b {
   background: green;
}
div.c {
   background: orange;
}
div.d {
   background: black;
   color: #fff;
}
div.e {
  background: pink;
}
.slider {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

**LIVE DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/CGBVF/20/**

Happy Coding :)